# XCode 13 and iOS 11.4 Simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode13

All simulators of 11 version and below are missed after updating XCode to 13 version. There is `iOS 11.4` in the list of available simulators:

Simulator list:

[image]

But I can't create simulator with this version because it doesn't appear in list when I try to select it:

Create simulator window:

[image]

Is there any way to run the simulator for at least 11.4 version of iOS?

Comment: The same problem, but even worse: I can see minimum iOS 12.4 simulator. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: after installing Xcode 13.3.1 I noticed iOS 11.x simulators are gone.

Comment: Personally I had to install XCode 12 ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Reference https://www.jianshu.com/p/4d32030be6b8
To modify Simulator iOS 11.4 Info.plist
path: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
environment: macOS 12.2.1 + Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).